# Setting up PhpStorm with Xdebug to my Docker setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, phpstorm, xdebug

I can't catch any request with Xdebug to my app. I want to setup for my Docker environment like my local environment.

This is my Dockerfile start lines:

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y unzip wget curl default-mysql-client libnss3-tools git
RUN apt-get install -y php php-fpm php-cli php-curl php-mysqlnd php-opcache php-pdo php-xml php-bcmath php-calendar \
                        php-ctype php-dom php-exif php-fileinfo php-ftp php-gd php-gettext \
                        php-iconv php-intl php-json php-mbstring php-mysqli php-gd php-mysql php-phar \
                        php-posix php-readline php-shmop php-simplexml php-soap php-sockets \
                        php-sysvmsg php-sysvsem php-sysvshm php-tokenizer php-wddx php-xmlreader \
                        php-xmlwriter php-xsl php-zip php-dev

#Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG 'serverName=DockerApp'

VOLUME /var/log/xdebug
ARG XDEBUG_HOST="192.168.1.102"
ARG XDEBUG_PORT=9021

RUN echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.profiler_enable=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_mode=req" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

This is my docker-compose.yml started lines.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: custome_web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./.docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./.docker/certs:/mycert
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "444:443"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host={{192.168.1.102}}
    links:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
```

If someone knows where I did wrong. Please advice me. I try everything but I do not find a solution for that...

Comment: 1) Is Xdebug actually installed and enabled? Just double check `phpinfo()` output for that. 2) I assume you are setting this up for a web page debug, right?

Comment: 3) Any reason to have `xdebug.remote_host` and `xdebug.remote_port` defined TWICE with different values? 4) Even have `XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host={{192.168.1.102}}` -- 3rd time... 5) Most importantly: you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`. With this option enabled Xdebug WILL IGNORE the value of `xdebug.remote_host` 6) Check Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output to confirm that it has desired values. 7) Also enable and collect Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect to (if it tries at all)

Comment: > 5) Most importantly: you have xdebug.remote_connect_back=1. With this option enabled Xdebug WILL IGNORE the value of xdebug.remote_host « that's not true. Xdebug will first try to use the remote_connect_back host, and then the remote_host setting.

Comment: @Derick *"that's not true"* Well, I see different mention in your docs (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back): "If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting **is ignored** and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request." 1) I see no mention of "will try to connect to `remote_host` if autodetected host has failed". 2) In quite few answers about Xdebug I saw "I had to disable remote_connect_back to have it working" kind of stuff.

Comment: @LazyOne Sounds like I need to fix the docs then?

Comment: @Derick I think you need to clarify it there how it works. I just want to point this: in some environments (Docker containers in particular I believe) the autodetected IP can be different to what is actually needs to be used in order to make a connection back to the host. With `remote_connect_back=1` Xdebug will try to connect to that autodetected host only; it will not try to make additional connection to `remote_host` if first one fails (it will show only 1 connection attempt in the log).

Comment: @Derick It's very easy to simulate on a local host: `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.0.33`. Autodetected IP will be 127.0.0.1. Xdebug will try to connect there and once failed it will not try to connect to a "valid" 192.0.168.0.33 (they both point to the same PC; for this to "work" I had to make no debug client listening -- to simulate "wrong IP" situation). https://postimg.cc/KKV4p4CK https://postimg.cc/pp6rkq4W  Hence the "is ignored" part is very valid here IMO: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host

Comment: Would you mind filing a bug report at https://bugs.php.net? I don't want to forget to check this, but this should work.

Comment: @Derick Bug report at php.net? About what? Right now I do not see anything that should be reported to PHP bug tracker (you may have misread/misinterpreted info in my comment). Perhaps you meant Xdebug's bug rracker instead?

Comment: @LazyOne I meant the not falling back to the configured remote_host/remote_port if the connect back host couldn't be contacted. I meant to write https://bugs.xdebug.org, but I've already filed it, and fixed it for Xdebug 3: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1832

Comment: @Derick I see. Thanks for looking into it and improving. I assume that the documentation for v3 will reflect this change in behaviour (for both remote_connect_back and remote_host).